# pipe not working for POST

Tags: node.js, post, express

Im starting to learn node.js, but come across a problem, cant find similar topics in stackoverflow so hopefully some one could point me in the right direction:)

its a really simple server with express

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express(); // Create server here
app.get('/',function(req,res){
//....
}).post('/',function(req,res){
    try{
        req.pipe(res);
    }catch (er) {
        res.end(er);
    }   
}).listen(8080);
```

if i replace the pipe call with

```
req.on('data',function(chunk){
            console.log(chunk.toString());
            res.end(chunk);
        });
```

it works. so what have i done wrong?

thanks guys

Comment: Hmm your code works fine for me. I'm using curl: `curl --data 'Hello world' http://localhost:8080` Can you be more specific about what isn't working?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, well for instance if we sending 'hello world' like u did, i expect the result to be shown after the terminal command, but when using pipe, after i hit enter at the end or curl, it doesn't show the message 'hello world' in terminal. i hope this time i explains things better